# C4018: Signed,unsigned mismatch inside a class

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
class SchoolManagementSystem
{
private:
       vector<Student> S;
       vector<Course> C;
public:
       SchoolManagementSystem();

       int getNumberOfStudents() const;
};
SchoolManagementSystem::SchoolManagementSystem() : S(), C() 
{}

int SchoolManagementSystem::getNumberOfStudents() 
const
{
    int numberOfStudents = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < S.size(); i ++)
        numberOfStudents ++;
    return numberOfStudents;
}
```

I'm working with a class presenting School Management System. (Above of this, I have some Student and Course class too)
The thing is at this line: **for ( int i = 0; i < S.size(); i ++)**, I got an error *warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch*. What is this error? Does it affect my result? How can I able to fix it?

Comment: BTW: why not `return (int)S.size()`?

Comment: Yes, I will do that! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The [`std::vector::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) function returns a [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) type, which is of `unsigned` type. Thus, in the comparison `i < S.size()` you are comparing a (`signed) int` with an `unsigned` value.

Just declare your `for` loop index as a `size_t` variable:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < S.size(); i++)
//...
```

In *most* cases, there won't be a problem with your comparison; but it is good practice not to ignore such warnings, as they *can* jump up and "bite-you-on-the-behind" when you least expect it.